# Navigation between multiple ios projects in an xcworkspace

Tags: ios, objective-c

We have developed 3 different projects(Three apps)named A,B,C which was created separately,
Now our client wants us to combine them into one app,Is it Possible?

Requirement: 
Project A : Manages sales orders for clients.
Project B : Keeps track of the Inventory
Project C : Monitors Customer feedback.

We need a home screen, which has 3 buttons and on clicking the button the corresponding process is invoked same as the individual app is doing right now.

NOTE: All 3 the projects have 5 storyboards & 30-40 class files each. Both are not a libraries.

I have gone through with workspace concept but can't get a clear idea. I created new workspace and added my 3 projects. But Iam not able to Navigate from storyboard 1 to storyboard 2.

Comment: Yes,In one project you can. You has to give identity to every project let a,b,c now you have to give navigation to the first project then say if userNeed == a{ navigation to the first viewcontroller of the a app }else if{ navigation to second app } else{ navigation to third app  }. i had done this type of project but i keep login system for that,so api reply me which type of project you have to open.

Comment: You might be able to navigate to the different storyboards by loading them via code using their file names. Then transition to the initial view controller of that storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ios Deep linking with different tags for each project.
for better understanding please follow this tutorial.
http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/04/22/deeplinking-in-ios/

Hope it will help!.

Comment: I know deeplink is used for Inter-app communication by launching an app from another app and passing information. but Can we use deep link to invoke different project inside an workspace. if yes can you please elaborate.

Comment: You can create a master project and other projects add as sub module.
let suppose you created master project E and added sub module A,B,C. 
From master project just call sub module A,B,C on a specific button action.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the right way is to create an additional *Core module* (which incapsulates networking, database wrapping etc), which will be imported to A, B, C, and an *App module*, which is what you want and which imports A, B, C to itself and uses them as needed.

Otherwise it's gonna be quite messy, unclear and poorly supportable.